# Find the limit of $(\frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{4} ...... \frac{2n -1}{2n})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit of $(\frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{4} ...... \frac{2n -1}{2n})$?

I have calculated it through calculating the limit of the general term $a_{n} = \frac{2n -1}{2n}$ and it was equal to 1, am I correct?

Comment: Maybe it's the limit of the *product* of your $a_k$ from $k=1$ to $n.$ [where $a_k=(2k-1)/(2k).$]

Comment: yes you are correct ..... my solution is wrong because it is a product not addition

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let
$$
a_n=\frac12\frac34\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}
$$
and
$$
b_n=\frac23\frac45\cdots\frac{2n}{2n+1}
$$
Then, because
$$
\frac k{k+1}\lt\frac{k+1}{k+2}
$$
we have
$$
a_n\lt b_n
$$
and therefore,
$$
a_n^2\lt a_nb_n=\frac1{2n+1}
$$
Thus,
$$
a_n\lt\frac1{\sqrt{2n+1}}
$$

Comment: Using the heavy machinery of the Gamma function, we can show that $$\frac1{\sqrt{\pi(n+1/2)}}\lt a_n\lt\frac1{\sqrt{\pi n\vphantom{()}}}$$

Answer (score 1):

You want to compute 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k}$$

You have that 
$$ \ln \left( \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k} \right) = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2k} \right)$$

Moreover, $$\ln \left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right) \sim - \frac{1}{2k}$$
which is the general term of a divergent series.

Therefore, the series $\sum \ln \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2k} \right)$ diverges to $-\infty$. So your original product converges to $0$.

Comment: I am not allowed to use series yet

Comment: Well, you should !... even if in this case, the other answer provides you a elementary proof.

Comment: How is $ln(1- (1/2k) )$ approximately equals $(- (1/2k)) $?

Comment: The symbol $\sim$ does not mean "approximately equal", but "equivalent". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis if you don't know what it means !

Comment: No,I want the proof of this claim

Comment: Ok. You have $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1)}{(1+x)-1} = \ln'(1)= \frac{1}{1} = 1$. So you get $\ln(1+x) \sim x$ near $0$. Now, when $k \rightarrow +\infty$, $-\frac{1}{2k} \rightarrow 0$ so replacing $x$ by $-\frac{1}{2k}$ in the previous equivalent gives you $\ln(1-\frac{1}{2k}) \sim - \frac{1}{2k}$.

Answer (score 1):

With a *Wallis' integral*:

It is known (and it can be proved by induction) that
$$\int_0^{\tfrac\pi 2}\sin^{2n}x\,\mathrm dx= \frac\pi2\,\frac{1\cdot 3\,\dots (2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\,\dots (2n)}$$
so $$\frac{1\cdot 3\,\dots (2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\,\dots (2n)}=\frac2\pi\int_0^{\tfrac\pi 2}\sin^{2n}x\,\mathrm dx,$$
and the integral converges to $0$ by the *dominated convergence theorem*.

Answer (score 0):

I. The limit of $a_n$ 
$$
a_n=\frac{2n-1}{2n}\implies a_n=1-\frac{1}{2n}
$$
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{1}{2n})=1
$$

---

II. The limit of your product (an approximation)

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot …\cdot\frac{2(n-1) -1}{2(n-1)} \cdot\frac{2n -1}{2n}=(1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{4})\cdot …\cdot(1-\frac{1}{2(n-1)})(1-\frac{1}{2n})
$$

The right side equals into:
$$
[1-0-\frac{1}{2}](1-\frac{1}{4})\cdot …\cdot(1-\frac{1}{2(n-1)})(1-\frac{1}{2n})
$$
$$
[1-\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4}](1-\frac{1}{6})\cdot …\cdot(1-\frac{1}{2(n-1)})(1-\frac{1}{2n})=
$$
$$[1-\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{6}](1-\frac{1}{8})\cdot …\cdot(1-\frac{1}{2(n-1)})(1-\frac{1}{2n})=
$$
$$[1-\frac{35}{48}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{8}](1-\frac{1}{10})\cdot …\cdot(1-\frac{1}{2(n-1)})(1-\frac{1}{2n})=
$$
$$[1-\frac{2887}{3840}-\frac{1}{10!!}](1-\frac{1}{12})\cdot …\cdot(1-\frac{1}{2(n-1)})(1-\frac{1}{2n})=
$$
$$...
$$
$$=1-A_n+(-1)^{n} \displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2j}
$$
What I can say about $A_n$ at least is
$$A_n\rightarrow 1+\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n!}
$$

Hence
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-A_n+(-1)^{n} \displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2j})=1-1 +0=0
$$

Comment: you mean that the limit is zero?

Comment: @Happy You got at least +2 independent proofs where the yes- the product decrease into zero (by going into endless). Just look: soon or late you get 0.2 which you multiple by 0.99, them you multiple by 0.999 etc. that get smaller cause you not multiple never by 1 or bigger then 1.